# TFS 2015, can we get Test request to show up on the kanban board?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, agile, scrum, kanban

we can have a Kanban board in TFS for Tasks. Is it possible, we can get "Test request" work item ,  to show up on the board ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about project management.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because project-management is off-topic on SO

Answer (score 1):

The test request seems a custom workitem type of your team project, to add a custom workitem type　to Kanban board. You could refer to this link: [Add a WIT to track like a requirement.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-wits-to-backlogs-and-boards#add-a-wit-to-track-it-like-a-requirement)

1. Export the work item definition file.
2. Edit the WIT definition to support planning tools. Details of this step, please refer to the link above. Each process template is a little different.
3. [Export the Categories file](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-categories) of your team project, edit like the code:

Code :

```
<CATEGORY name="Requirement Category" refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="User Story" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="test request" />
</CATEGORY>
```

4. [Export the process template file](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration), map the state to "Proposed", "InProgress", "Complete". There could only be one "Proposed" and one "Complete".
5. Add a color for your custom workitem.

   `<WorkItemColor primary="FF33CC33" secondary="FFD6F5D6" name="Service App" />`
6. Import your workitem definiton and categories and process configure files in turn.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Good to know that there is way.  Will tryout and let you know.

Comment: @chandu Is there any feedback, did you solved it?

Comment: Hi, not yet. the whole team has not agreed for this change. so have to wait .